# MS Access Running Count in time series by ID

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to add a running count to a time series table by API number.  The running count would be an indicator of what production month a given well is in.

Table: MonthlyProd
Fields: API, YEAR, MONTH, LIQUID
Desired Field: RunningCount

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73gpb.jpg)

I cannot quite figure out a Dcount expression in MS Access.

Edit* Current progress is as follows.  Using the following Access query
ProdMonth: DCount("API","Monthly Production","API=" & [API] & " AND (YEAR<" & [YEAR] & " OR (YEAR=" & [YEAR] & " AND MONTHNUMBER<=" & [MONTHNUMBER] & "))")

Yields the following results
[Running Total Not quite there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REUlu.jpg)

I assume I am off in the logic statement somewhere?

Comment: What method would you want to be attempting to do this with? (e.g. Access Query, SQL, VBA, etc.)

Comment: Access query would be great but I am open to all options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I needed to format the Month and Year into a date serial number in one field.

The correct DCount function was as follows:

```
    ProdMonth: DCount("API","MonthlyFix","API=" & [API] & " AND DateSer<=" & [DateSer])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DCOUNT("API","MonthlyProd","API=" & API & " AND (YEAR<" & YEAR & " OR (YEAR=" & YEAR & " AND MONTH<" & MONTH & "))")
```

This assumes `API`, `MONTH`, `YEAR` are numerical.

Comment: Getting much closer.  I edited the original question with results